# Is there a prestige class called "Chosen Of Mystra"?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, forgotten-realms, prestige-class

I would like to know if there's a prestige class named "Chosen Of Mystra". I've read a lot about it in stories, but can't find anything in the rulebooks.

Is it a fictional PC only or is it described somewhere? If so: where?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is from the Forgotten Realms campaign setting.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystra_%28Forgotten_Realms%29 
http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Chosen_of_Mystra

It is not a prestige class. It is a template. It is published in the campaign setting book.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs The Chosen of Mystra template was never intended for PCs, and is wildly overpowered for them. It was intended for powerful plot-device-with-feet NPCs like Elminster and the Seven Sisters.

Answer (score 1):

In the 3.x *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* (Greenwood, Reynolds, Williams, Heinsoo; ISBN-10 0786918365), there are some details about the *Chosen of Mystra* on p247. They are described as having:

- One bonus spell of each spell level, which is a single spell that cannot change, and can be used as a spell-like ability. So, if your first level bonus spell choice is *magic missile* you cannot change it to another spell, but you cast as an ability.
- Spell immunity to one spell of each level. Again, once chosen it cannot be changed.
- Immunity to aging, disease, disintegration, and poison. They do not need to sleep, but must still rest to memorize spells.
- *Detect magic*, line of site range.
- Use of *silver fire*.
- +10 enhancement bonus to constitution.

While I am not opposed to characters in a FR campaign becoming one of the super-powerful residents, I would say that this is not a prestige class because you do not choose to be Chosen. I am no Realms historian, but I must assume Elminster was Chosen at birth (if not before), even if there was a "meeting with the goddess" moment where he may have been formally Chosen.

A campaign where a Level 1 wizard is Chosen could be interesting. I would play it with the character (and the player) not knowing they are Chosen, but occassionally noticing strange powers. Make them learn their abilities as they go, then at some plot-critical point let them know the truth.

Side notes: The FR Campaign Setting is a pretty awesome book, and worth finding for Realms fans. Also, I do not seem to have my *Magic of Faerun* book any more, which likely has more details.

Comment: I would agree that the template is not meant for PCs simply because it lacks a Level Adjustment entry. Templates intended for PCs normally have one, even if it specifies +0 (like the Aquatic or Arctic templates).

Comment: I looked up Storm Silverhand in the FRCS and they had "(Chosen of Mystra)" after her name, rather than in their class listing.